# How to use ERB to generate a unique id for a submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, capybara, erb

I have been updating my forms, and now have a modal in one form that allows for the creation of a linked model. Both the modal and the form itself have a button named "Save", which I'm targeting with Capybara to check that the objects get created successfully using:

```
(page).click_button('Save')
```

Now that I've added the modal, there are two buttons with the same name and I want to pass them a different id to the one auto generated by the ERB code:

```
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-success"%>
```

How do I do this with ERB? I've tried using html: { id: "Something else" }, but that doesn't work.

Alternatively, is there another mechanism to get capybara to click a specific button (e.g. click_button_first('Save') or similar (I can't seem to find anything on this in the documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are two buttons with the same name and I want to pass them a different id to the one auto generated by the ERB code

You can give ids to submit buttons like this:

```
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", id: "some-id"%>
```

> Alternatively, is there another mechanism to get capybara to click a specific button

If you don't want to assign ids then you can simply nest your button selector appropriately and then use it, something like this:

```
page.find(".btn").click #this will target button with class btn
page.find("#some-modal-id .btn").click #this will target button inside a modal
```

Comment: Thanks - I used the latter method to just target the buttons inside a css selector

Answer (score 0):

In view you can do this:

```
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" id:'btn_id'%>
```

In Step definitions you can do this

```
find(:xpath, "xpath_of_btn").click
find("#btn_id").find("Save").click
```